# Parsing Nation stock exchange data and creating chart

Tags: php, jquery, parsing, stock

I am trying to fetch National Stock Exchange Data and create chart using Google charts. But I am clueless how to parse the data that I am getting using the api. Here's the code of api. Any help will be appreciated. Output looks like this http://theawesomecoder.com/calc/chart.php

```
<?php
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-10007&symbol=NIFTY&symbol=NIFTY&instrument=OPTIDX&date=-&segmentLink=17&segmentLink=17');
curl_setopt($curlSession,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$homepage = curl_exec($curlSession);



var_dump($homepage);

curl_close($curlSession);
?>
```

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: Which column of the data are you interested in?

Comment: i have put the link of how the output looks like http://theawesomecoder.com/calc/chart.php

Comment: That's ok. But which column do you want to parse out and chart? There is a gazillion columns there.

Comment: i want to parse the column Strike Price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do the job properly, you should do this all on server side and for that please refer to this answer:

[How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Otherwise this should solve your problem in a quicker way:

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function(){
         var strikePrice = new Array();
         $(".opttbldata").find("tr").each( function (row, currentTR) {
            if (row > 1) { // Avoid first two header rows (0 based index)
                var columnContent = $(currentTR).find("td:eq( 6 )").text();
                strikePrice[row-2] = (columnContent=="-"?" 0":columnContent); // Strike price column (0 based index)
            }
         });
         $("#NSEIndiaData").remove(); // Get rid of the loaded page/data to uncluter the DOM
         alert(strikePrice);
      });
   </script>
</head>

<body>
   <?php
      $curlSession = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-10007&symbol=NIFTY&symbol=NIFTY&instrument=OPTIDX&date=-&segmentLink=17&segmentLink=17');
      curl_setopt($curlSession,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
      curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $homepage = curl_exec($curlSession);
   ?>

   <div id="NSEIndiaData" style="display: none;">
      <?php var_dump($homepage); ?>
   </div>

   <?php
      curl_close($curlSession);
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

All values of column 12 will be placed inside a 0 index based Array which you can later manipulate at will.

Comment: suppose i want parse Ask Qty column which is just before Strike Price what changes i need to make in the code. Regards

Comment: i tried to make changes like this but its not working  strikePrice[row-2] = $(currentTR).find("td:eq( 10 )").text();

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? **[Here](http://fabriciosantos.info/playground/test.php)** it works fine. But of course there are some cells who have a dash "-" which I suppose means it's a zero.

Comment: yes so i want to get 0 instead of those dash in the alert being displayed

Comment: And i complete agree that you have been very helpful

Comment: Mate... You are lazying now... :-) All you need to do is check the value and if it is equal to `-` then store `0` otherwise store the value. Anyway, the **[page is changed](http://fabriciosantos.info/playground/test.php)** to accommodate the need. Please mind that I used the `Net Chng` column because the `Ask Qty` had no `-` today.

Comment: i am so sorry for that i just implemented it. Thank you once again for the help